# topology problem in the python script(arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, topology

I'm using Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.1.
I have one topology problem in my Python script and I don't know how to fix it.
I have one road and I want to select polygons with a query where intersect
with my road(or my road within the polygons).  But my bad road have very small section where intersect with others polygons if I use easy way with a query then
query select all polygons(and polygons where intersect with the small sections), I don't want that I don't need 
small road section and I don't want the intersect polygons with this section.
Any idea how to fix that using Python and Arcpy ?

Comment: +1 Would be very interested in seeing ways to access arcobjects methods like `ITopologyGraph.SetParentSelected`.

Comment: its difficult python topology ?

Comment: Years ago Esri made a big deal about _topology_, saying that was what differentiated GIS from CAD.  From what I can tell, they have not included any arcpy functions that let you do the sorts of queries you have described.  It can be done with ArcObjects.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me.  Maybe you can accomplish what you need by using a spatial join, without using topology. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm

Comment: then i think so must be use python functions and not arcpy